# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '(0,t(r(d[3])).default)().apiUrl' release channel android problem

Tags: android, react-native, axios, environment-variables, expo

I got this problem when i expo publish my react native app with or without `--release-channel dev` flag.
I set up a config file environment.js to get different release version like this :

```
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import { Platform } from "react-native";

const localhost = Platform.OS === "ios" ? "localhost:8080" : "10.0.2.2:8080";

const ENV = {
  localhost: {
    //apiUrl: localhost,
    apiUrl: "http:xxxx",
  },
  dev: {
    apiUrl: "http:xxxx",
  },
  staging: {
    apiUrl: "http:xxxx",
    // Add other keys you want here
  },
  prod: {
    apiUrl: "http:xxxx",
    // Add other keys you want here
  },
};

const getEnvVars = (env = Constants.manifest.releaseChannel) => {
  // What is __DEV__ ?
  // This variable is set to true when react-native is running in Dev mode.
  // __DEV__ is true when run locally, but false when published.
  if (__DEV__ || env === undefined || env === null || env === "") {
    return ENV.localhost;
  } else if (env.indexOf("dev") !== -1) {
    return ENV.dev;
  } else if (env.indexOf("staging") !== -1) {
    return ENV.staging;
  } else if (env.indexOf("prod") !== -1) {
    return ENV.prod;
  }
};

export default getEnvVars;
```

I intercept the config with creation of new intance of axios like this :

```
import axios from "axios";
import { getKey } from "./deviceStorage";

import getEnvVars from "../../environment";
const { apiUrl } = getEnvVars();

const instance = axios.create({
  // .. where we make our configurations
  baseURL: apiUrl,
});

instance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  const token = getKey("id_token");
  token.then((value) => {
    config.headers.Authorization = value ? `Bearer ${value}` : "";
  });
  return config;
});

export default instance;
```

when i emulate on my device everything work fine but when i expo publish and scan QR code with my device the app crash after splash screen and i got this error say :

[image]

So if i understand well the Constants.manifest.releaseChannel is undefined, any idea why this happen ? do i miss somthing on the import ?

When i put the Api URL directly on my axios interceptors everything work fine.
    import axios from "axios";
    import { getKey } from "./deviceStorage";

```
//import getEnvVars from "../../environment";
//const { apiUrl } = getEnvVars();

const instance = axios.create({
  // .. where we make our configurations
  baseURL: "http://xxxx",
});

instance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  const token = getKey("id_token");
  token.then((value) => {
    config.headers.Authorization = value ? `Bearer ${value}` : "";
  });
  return config;
});

export default instance;

export const ApiUrls = {
  authPatient: "/xxx",
  authPractician: "/xxx",
};
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my problem here and maybe will help anyone on the future so :
i delete the `env` parameter on the `getEnvVars` and i declared inside the function and everything work fine :

```
const getEnvVars = () => {
  const env = Constants.manifest.releaseChannel;
  if (!__DEV__ && env) {
    switch (env) {
      case env.indexOf("dev") !== -1:
        return ENV.dev;
      case env.indexOf("staging") !== -1:
        return ENV.staging;
      case env.indexOf("prod") !== -1:
        return ENV.prod;
      default:
        return ENV.localhost;
    }
  }
  return ENV.localhost;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Moving the declaration of `env` into the function didn't work for me so I cut out the function altogether and that fixed my issue up. Going to have to figure out a way to rewrite it. But thank you for posting this anyways

Comment: There is a little answering aspect in this post. But could you please make it more obvious? Maybe by [edit]ing according to [answer].